# Jenkins not loading after fresh install on Fedora

Tags: jenkins, fedora

I just did a fresh install of Jenkins on Fedora, following this page: https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/

Everything installed without any issues. However, when going to http://localhost:8080 I get just a white page:
[image]

Would you please be able to indicate what might be the issue? Below you can find some additional information that might help.

Thank you!

---

When I do nmap localhost I can see that the HTTP 8080 is up:

```
[root@localhost jenkins]# nmap localhost

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-05-11 23:59 CEST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000010s latency).
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): ::1
Not shown: 998 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
631/tcp  open  ipp
8080/tcp open  http-proxy

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.62 seconds
```

I can also see that the jenkins service is up:

```
[root@localhost jenkins]# systemctl status jenkins.service
● jenkins.service - Jenkins continuous build server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2018-05-11 23:44:30 CEST; 15min ago
  Process: 3790 ExecStop=/usr/libexec/jenkins/jenkins stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 3862 ExecStart=/usr/libexec/jenkins/jenkins start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 3936 (java)
    Tasks: 54 (limit: 4673)
   Memory: 454.9M
   CGroup: /system.slice/jenkins.service
           └─3936 /etc/alternatives/java -Dcom.sun.akuma.Daemon=daemonized -Djava.awt.headless=true -DJENKINS_HOME=/var/l>

May 11 23:44:30 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Jenkins continuous build server...
May 11 23:44:30 localhost.localdomain runuser[3919]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session opened for user jenkins by (uid=0)
May 11 23:44:30 localhost.localdomain runuser[3919]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session closed for user jenkins
May 11 23:44:30 localhost.localdomain jenkins[3862]: Starting Jenkins [  OK  ]
May 11 23:44:30 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started Jenkins continuous build server.
```

If I check my java version I get:

```
[root@localhost jenkins]# java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_162"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_162-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.162-b12, mixed mode)
```

When I try to access it with Curl:

```
[fabio@localhost ~]$ curl http://localhost:8080
[fabio@localhost ~]$
```

Comment: Check what happens when you use curl to connect to the server. Also check the jenkins logs (if any).

Comment: Hi, when I Curl it nothing comes up. I just updated the question with that information so you can have a look. It is in the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work by verifying the logs and seeing what was going wrong. It was asking for Apache Jelly and DOM4J. After installing these two packages, Jenkins worked.